# Office 365 Users Connector is missing in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am using office 365 developer program and i've Power Apps Per User Plan trial.  I am developing an app on powerapp and i would like to connect with Office 365 Users connector to get profile information of user but i am not able to find Office 365 Users connector in my connectors list. Please see attached screenshot 1. Is it something related to my office 365 developer program?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7OhA.png)

However i can see Microsoft Office 365 users in my connector list instead of Office 365 Users. Please see attached screenshot 2

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkvoX.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office 365 business applications have recently been renamed to Microsoft 365. In this context it makes sense to rename the connector for Office 365 Users to Microsoft 365 Users. It still has the same office icon.

Try using this connector and when following tutorials with the older naming, just silently repeat in your head "Office 365 is now Microsoft 365".

Comment: Thanks for the information and yes i found functions under Microsoft 365 users connection.